# Eclipse not recognizing generated class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have used Maven plugin to generate classes in my project. However even after trying padding it explicitly from project build path, eclipse is unable to recognize it. It says,

**"AbcBaseListener cannot be resolved to a type"**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Project auto build is also ON.

Comment: Can you please add the header of your generated `AbcBaseListener.java` ? In which package does it live?

Comment: You can see in screenshot, its under target->gtenerated-sources->antlr4.

Comment: No, i am curious what is inside that generated .java

Comment: @GyroGearless I have edited screenshot now.

Comment: Thanks @GyroGearless I found reason, I updated that into answer of Aaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check 2 things:

**1)**
The important hint here is "class folder". Eclipse expects `.class` files in there, source code will be ignored.

To fix this, add this plugin to your POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/generated-sources/</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and update the project (Maven -> Update ...).

The other option would be to manually add another *source folder* to the build path but that will get lost whenever m2e updates the project configuration from the POM.

**2)** Make sure your generated files are having package names;

Use below code inside your g4 file after **grammar Abc**;

```
@header {
    package antlr4;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it didn't work. (I updated screenshot in question). Can you please elaborate little bit more on your answer?

Comment: Ok I found the reason, there were multiple reasons, 1st one it the one solved from your solution,2nd is, the generated file was not creating package names. Thanks :)